# Inequality on pairs of projections in Kato's book

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, perturbation-theory, projection

I  do not understand an argument (p. 58, l.2--3) regarding two "close" projections, in the proof of Theorem I.6.34, pp. 56--58, Kato's book "Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators".

The setting is in a Hilbert space $H$ (Chapter I is about finite dimensional spaces, but in the theorem below it does not seem the finiteness matters)

**First, I introduce the setting.**
The assumption:

> Theorem 6.34. Let $P , Q$ be two orthogonal projections with $M = R(P)$, $N = R(Q)$ such that $\|(1-Q) P\|=\delta<1$.

In the proof we show

> (6.55) $\ \|(1-P) Q_{0}\| \leq \delta=\|(1-Q) P\|$,

where $Q_0:H\to Im(Q|_{M})$ is an orthogonal projection.

**Then, here is what I do not understand.**
On p. 58 he writes

> Applying the above result (6.55) to the pair $P,Q$ replaced by $Q_0,P$, we thus obtain $\left\|\left(1-Q_{0}\right) P\right\| \leqq\left\|(1-P) Q_{0}\right\|$.

But I do not know what this means. The final goal in this line is to show $\left\|\left(1-Q_{0}\right) P\right\| \leqq\left\|(1-P) Q_{0}\right\|$, so I tried to mimic the arguments to derive (6.55), but cannot figure out how.

Comment: So are you saying if you go back to the start and replace thm 6.34 with "Let $Q_0,P$ be two orthog. proj. with ... ", you can't derive $\left\|\left(1-Q_{0}\right) P\right\| \leq\left\|(1-P) Q_{0}\right\|$?

Comment: Yes thats what it means, and no, $P,Q$ turns into $Q_0,P$ not $P,Q_0$. Applying 6.55 means something like using the logical statement "assumptions of thm 6.34 with $P,Q$ implies 6.55". If this statement is  $\mathfrak P(P,Q)$ then you're asked to look at $\mathfrak P(Q_0,P)$

Comment: @CalvinKhor Oh I meant $\|(1-Q_0)P_0\|\leq \delta':= \| (1-P) Q_0\|$, where we know $\|(1-P)Q_0\|=\delta'\leq\delta <1$ and $P_0:H\to P(N_0)$ is the orthogonal projection. What I meant is there is $P_0$. I am trying to show $P_0=P$, not sure if this is a good way, but not succeeding with this anyway... I know I am meant to use $P:N_0\to M$ is bijective I just don't get it...

Comment: Sorry the choice of the notation $P_0$ was a bad choice. This is not the same as $P_0$ on p. 58. Let's name it $P'_0$. $P'_0:H\to P(N_0)$. This is the same as $Q_0$, which one'd get if one starts from $(P,Q)$. If one starts from $(Q_0,P)$, then one would get $P'_0$ and the new (6.55)' reads $\|(1-Q_0)P'_0\|\leq \|(1-P)Q_0\|$. But this is not the same as $\|(1-Q_0)P\|\leq \|(1-P)Q_0\|$

Comment: I've run out of time for now, so I've cleaned up my comments above slightly to free up some space. Good luck

Comment: @CalvinKhor Your comments proved helpful when diving into Kato's book, and finally writing an answer.

Comment: @Hanno glad it helped more than i anticipated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially, Kato assumes that $P$ and $Q$ are orthogonal projectors satisfying
$\,\|(1-Q)P\|<1$. He then proves
$$\|(1-P)\,Q_0\|\:\leqslant\:\|(1-Q)P\,\|\tag{6.55}$$
where $Q_0$ is the orthogonal projector onto
$N_0\!:=\,\operatorname{Im}\left(Q|_{\operatorname{Im}P}\right) \,=\,\operatorname{Im}(QP)\,$.

$(6.55)$ shows that $Q_0$ and $P$ also satisfy the initial assumptions, hence
$$\|(1-Q_0)\,Z\|\:\leqslant\:\|(1-P)\,Q_0\|\tag{see page 58, line 3}$$
follows, this times with $Z$ being the orthogonal projector onto
$$\operatorname{Im}\left(P|_{\operatorname{Im}Q_0}\right) \,=\,\operatorname{Im}(PQ_0)\,.$$
But in fact one has $Z=P\,$ because $\operatorname{Im}(PQ_0)=\operatorname{Im}(P)\,$. The preceding equality follows from section I.4.6 in Kato's book, which applies to the pair $P,Q_0\,$ as these are close by since $\|P-Q_0\|<1$ holds by $(6.58)$.